# Socket.IO Restoring a broken connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, restore

In a client-server application, I send a string to the server in a separate thread:

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(_dos);
dataOutputStream.flush();
```

But I get in another thread java.net.SocketException: Connection reset in the line:

```
mes = dataInputStream.readUTF();
```

At the same time, the server does not receive anything (I checked this in wireshark) and continues to listen to the socket.

The question is: is it possible, if the client socket is damaged, but the server socket is working, to restore the operation of the client socket and thus restore the client-server connection, without restarting both?

Comment: close the socket and connect another one.

Comment: dangling-else it won't work without restarting both. Because there will be an error on the server: The address is already in use.

Comment: I think you don't understand the difference between a socket on which you listen for incoming connections, and [a socket on which you accept the connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--).  The first is one per server (one per port, really) and the second is one per connection. It is the latter you need to close on the server.  Meanwhile, the client closes its only socket, and reconnects to the server.

Comment: That's a typical server design - the server runs 'forever', accepting new connections, each of which get its own new socket, and closing that socket when the particular conversation is finished (or failed).

Comment: Server operation, ping-pong, opening and closing of new connections have already been implemented. I am interested in the possibility of saving the interrupted (SocketException: Connection reset) from the client side of the socket. At the same time, the socket server is still running.

Comment: The connection is gone. You need to connect again. Generally speaking, TCP implementations do not allow you to issue a connect on a socket that has become disconnected. You can try, but it's safest to make a new socket object. Even if it works for you, the result may be non-portable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am also inclined to this decision. Apparently it will be easier this way.

Comment: ok. good luck.  maybe I should move that last comment to an answer...

Answer (score 1):

The connection is gone. On the client side, you will need to connect again.

Generally speaking, TCP implementations do not allow you to issue a connect on a socket that has become disconnected. You can try, but it's safest to make a new socket object. Even if it works for you, the result may be non-portable.

The server of course also has a socket on a defunct connection, so it needs to close its end.  A new socket will be created on 'accepting' the new connection from the client.